# How can I set a time limit on the Recycle Bin?

Tags: windows-7, windows, recycle-bin

How can I set a time limit on Windows 7 Recycle Bin?

> **What is the Recycle Bin?**
>
> The Recycle Bin in Windows 7 Starter is a file to restore deleted
>   files. They are kept there indefinitely.

But, how can I make it **not** indefinite?

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I set a time limit on Windows 7 Recycle Bin?

You can't. However, you can set the maximum **size** of the recycle bin.

If the size of the items in the Recycle Bin exceed this size, then **Windows will start deleting items on a First-In-First-Out (FIFO) basis**.

> **Recycle Bin size**
>
> The Recycle Bin size calculations are based on the user’s disk quota
>   and not the disk size. In Windows XP, the default Recycle Bin was 10%
>   of the user’s quota on the volume. In later versions of Windows, the
>   default size is 10% of the first 40GB of quota, and 5% of any quota
>   above which is above 40GB.
>
> To change its capacity, right-click on the Recycle Bin icon >
>   Properties. Here under the General tab, you can set the maximum size
>   for your Recycle Bin.
>
> If you wish, you can also change the size and settings on a per-folder
>   basis. More on this at [TechNet Blogs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/07/16/managing-the-recycle-bin-with-redirected-folders-with-vista-or-windows-7/).
>
> **Tweak Recycle Bin behavior**
>
> Right-Click on the Recycle Bin icon and select Properties. Here you
>   will be able to changes a few of its settings. As I mentioned, each
>   Drive has its own Recycle Bin.
>
> Select the Drive.
>
> You will then be able to decide the maximum size of the Bin. This
>   means that if the items in the Bin exceed this number, then Windows
>   will start deleting items on a First-In-First-Out (FIFO) basis. You
>   can increase the size of Recycle Bin if you feel.

Source [Windows Recycle Bin Tricks and Tips](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-recycle-bin-tricks-tips)

Example Screenshot:

[image]